# Convert String to Python datetime Object without Zero Padding

Tags: python, string, datetime, python-datetime

I'm using python 3.5.

I have a string formatted as `mm/dd/yyyy H:MM:SS AM/PM` that I would like as a python datetime object.

Here is what I've tried.

```
    date = "09/10/2015 6:17:09 PM"
    date_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
```

But this gets an error because the hour is not zero padded. The formatting was done per the table on the
[datetime documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior), which does not allow the hour to have one digit.

I've tried splitting the date up, adding a zero and then reassembling the string back together, while this works, this seems less robust/ideal.

```
    date = "09/10/2015 6:17:09 PM"
    date = date.split()
    date = date[0] + " 0" + date[1] + " " + date[2]
```

Any recommendation on how to get the `datetime` object directly, or a better method for padding the hour would be helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: I got `2015-10-09 18:17:09` as output in python 2.7. can you share specific exception. and which version of python are you on?

Comment: This is not the cause of the problem, but you state that the date string is formatted as `mm/dd/yyyy`, but the code assumes `'%d/%m/%Y`, i.e. day and month are interchanged.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with this code:

```
>>> date = "09/10/2015 6:17:09 PM"
>>> date_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
>>> date_obj
datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 10, 18, 17, 9)
>>> print(date_obj)
2015-09-10 18:17:09
```

The individual attributes of the `datetime` object are integers, not strings, and the internal representation uses 24hr values for the hour.

Note that I have swapped the day and month in the format strings as you state that the input format is `mm/dd/yyyy`.

But it seems that you actually want it as a string with zero padded hour, so you can use `datetime.strftime()` like this:

```
>>> date_str = date_obj.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
>>> print(date_str)
09/10/2015 06:17:09 PM

# or, if you actually want the output format as %d/%m/%Y....
>>> print(date_obj.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p'))
10/09/2015 06:17:09 PM
```